# ng2-toastr with akveo/ng2-admin - CSS not taken into account

Tags: angular, typescript, toastr

I'm using akveo/ng2-admin dashboard (latest with angular 4) and tried to use ng2-toastr following the installation doc.

I imported the CSS in the index.html file and declared the ToastModule in the app.module.ts file.

I also imported the ToastsManager in my component and assigned the ViewContainerRef.

The module gets loaded successfully and everything goes without error so far.

But when I call `this.toastr.success('You are awesome!', 'Success!');` the text is displayed without using the CSS.

ng2-admin is using WebPack.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!
Serge.

URL toastr: https://github.com/PointInside/ng2-toastr

URL ng2-admin: [enter link description here](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the CSS file in the **theme** folder and loaded it in the app.component.ts with the following command:

```
import 'style-loader!./theme/ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr.scss';
```

Cheers,
Serge.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
@import '../node_modules/ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr.css';
```

to `./src/app/theme/theme.cscc`

this file is there to add global styles or import other files, that way we can avoid copying files

Comment: But after, I will transpile it to the production system in the dist directory and I need the css to be in the assets dir to be taken into account.